# Insert wrong value in database through NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

When I want to insert a `float` value like `400.79`, it's automatically inserting `400.790008544922` in NHibernate. So, why is it inserting the wrong value?

Comment: Which database is nhibernate targetting and what is the datatype of the column in the table?

Answer (score 2):

I expect your float to pass through a double, either in your code or in the NHibernate mapping to the underlying datatable.

If I try this in LINQPad:

```
float f = 400.79F;
double d = f;
d.Dump();
```

The output is: `400,790008544922`

Based on [this blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/nhibernate-3-data-type-mapping-for-sql-server/) that describes NHibernate mappings from .Net Types to SqlServer datatypes only a datacolumn of type REAL (synonym for FLOAT(24))  maps to a float (Single), other non integer number datatypes maps to either double or decimal.